# profit vs loss - preventing one from making profit equals gezel?

Tags: internet, gezel-stealing

so I visited webpage with AdBlock ON, and this is what appeared on my screen
[image]

So I am asking, not making a profit equals gezel?

Comment: @doubleAA Doesn't sound like a dupe to me. That question was asking if adblocking is mutar. This one's asking if not [enabling someone else's means of] making a profit is halachik gezel (min hatorah). It's both more gnereal and more specific.

Comment: (and the answer is: of course not. They don't own your monitor and can't tell you what to display on it. Misrepresenting halacha in order to turn a profit, however, is certainly assur.)